# What is the best way to handle classes descended from the same base class in a collection?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, factory

My language is C#.

I have a set of seven classes that all ultimately derive from a single class. The image of the class diagram is posted below. I will frequently need to iterate through collections where the members are all the seven classes intermixed. An example collection might look like this:

```
Collection: A, D, C, A,..., B
```

No two collections would have the same mix of elements or the same order of elements.

I think I understand the basic idea of creating classes using the factory pattern but I have never used one before.

My issue is I need to do various things with each of these elements. Some elements share common methods (perhaps they inherited the method from the top base class) and some have unique methods/properties that none of the others have. I find myself having to do a lot of detecting what element I have and then casting to that element. This smells like I am doing the wrong thing as I see now I will have to create the same detection code and do the casting over and over again.

Is there a better way that I need to be handling these classes?

[image]

Adding info on the classes...

The classes use three different types of CAD files. One CAD file for each class. The three CAD files make seven different types of "things". The underlying API of the CAD files is based on com and was first released in 1995. It has had many yearly changes over the years. The API is pretty convoluted now because of this.

The seven classes detail my "things". All of the "things" share some basic information like file meta data (name, path, file type, etc) but they all also have different uses and therefore need different classes.
One of the main classes is an assembly that holds components. The components can be a part or another assembly. It is recursive with the possibility of multiple layers of assemblies referencing assemblies referencing assemblies.

The class structure is set up to consolidate the methods and properties that are common at the top and and as you progress each level down they diverge. This strategy was to prevent duplication of code.

I have seen that Interfaces should only have things that are related together. If you were to look at any one class it would be made up of a lot of different kinds of completely different methods and properties that are totally unrelated to each other. Kind of like how motors, tires, body parts, etc of a car are unrelated. The only way they would be related is that they would be in the same class.

If I wrote a post on what each class is it would make up a very complicated book. That is why I did not post more detailed information - we would end up getting mired in the details.

Something that was helpful is knowing that I can do the following using Interfaces:

```
public void DoSomething(ISomeInterface value)
{
    value.action();
}
```

This was a new concept to me - that was very, very helpful. My simple understanding of Interfaces before asking this question was that they create a "contract" that helps keep an API consistent over time. I did not understand that they could be used for polymorphism.

I **think** my course to better code here relies in trying to flatten the classes without duplication code and using Interfaces to their full extent.

Thank you all for challenging my thinking - I am grateful and of course up for more of that!

Comment: What do you know about interfaces?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Some. That is how I started. It just seemed to make the project more complex without adding improved functionality. In what way would Interfaces improve the type checking I would need to do?

Comment: _"In what way would Interfaces improve the type checking I would need to do?"_ In that way that you could do type checking for just those functionalites you'll need to handle over all these elements in the collection rather than refering to concrete types.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Like the way https://www.interfacett.com/videos/understanding-c-interfaces-polymorphic-behavior-dan-wahlin/ uses an Interface as a parameter of a method?

Comment: I am not watching videos, sorry. If you want to clarify something about your question put that in text form to your question please.

Comment: *"This smells like I am doing the wrong thing"* - absolutely, it does. Unfortunately, there is no way to tell how to improve this without knowing the classes, their methods, the algorithm or task which calls these methods. It seems you are looking for a silver bullet, where only going through the gory details could help, sorry.

Comment: If you are processing these objects differently, why are you storing them in the same collection?

Comment: As been said already, with the vague info provided you're at best going to get vague answers and suggestions. Following that train of thought, *if it makes sense in the overall design*, you might consider having a "Process this" method in the base class that the inheriting classes override as additional class-specific methods that need called are added; so your loop is just `N.ProcessThis()`.

Comment: We can't see the details of the classes on the diagram; the hierarchy is possibly too elaborate, though. There are two options to consider. Case (1): all of the calling code can be expressed by only using the methods of the base class (without ever doing type checks); if so, put all the objects in a single collection and use them polymorphically. Case (2): you *must* work differently with different subclasses; then, put each kind in it's own collection and write code in terms of concrete types. (Also make these considerations for a subtree of the inheritance hierarchy).

Comment: Your image is insufficient resolution to view properly.

Comment: @Eric _"In what way would Interfaces improve the type checking I would need to do?"_ You're nearing an XY problem here. Type checking is what you _shouldn't_ do, and interfaces help you avoid it by giving your types a common interface which removes the need to know what type an object is (other than the interface in question - which you should know from the get go)

Comment: @Eric "It just seemed to make the project more complex without adding improved functionality" - just to clarify something, it's helpful to understand this; you are talking about the C# *interface types* here (declared with the `interface` keyword), but in software design the word "interface" in general refers to the set of public methods and other public methods exposed by a class (or a module). Each one of your classes has a public interface, and furthermore, it provides the abstract (generalized) interface for each of its subsclasses. 1/2

Comment: @Eric What you need to determine is if the code that uses those classes can be written so that it is only calling the methods of the base class (or if those base class methods can be changed up somehow to make this possible). Often, if you are doing type checking, you are really taking code that should be placed in those other classes, and writing it at the call site. This is not always the case, and if that code cannot really be pushed into those classes, you'll have to store the instances separately, or do the type checks. 2/2

Answer (score 4):

> My issue is I need to do various things with each of these elements.

This is a problem of not "getting" OOP. (Don't worry, it's been around for 50 years and most developers don't really get it.)

Can you think of a single word that encompasses all those various things? If you can, make your classes implement an interface that has a method whose name includes the word you thought of. Treat all the objects as instances of that interface type. No more type checks; just call the method that does the thing.

If you have trouble naming this method, then maybe you need to rethink your entire design. If the objects are really that dissimilar, they probably have no business being in the same type hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

**Never pile things together if you intend to treat them differently**.

Let's take a simplified example:

```
List<object> myList = new List<object>()
{
    new Foo(),
    new Bar(),
    new Baz()
};
```

Putting items in an `object` list should only be done if you intend to treat this list's items as objects, not as some more specific derived type.

This makes sense:

```
foreach(var item in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Every `object` has a `ToString()` method, which means you're able to treat all these items the same way.

This doesn't make sense:

```
foreach(var item in myList)
{
    if(item is Foo myFoo)
        Console.WriteLine(myFoo.FooValue);
    else if(item is Bar myBar)
        Console.WriteLine(myBar.BarValue);
    else if(item is Baz myBaz)
        Console.WriteLine(myBaz.BazValue);
}
```

Since everything needed to be treated differently, then it didn't make sense to first cast them to the exact same type. The casting was counterproductive since you were forced to manually undo it.

What you're doing here is basically lumping completely different things together, which then forces you to sort them again, which is just doing more work for no gain. Think of it this way:

I need you to sharpen my knives, bend my spoons, and paint my forks. I have two drawers, we'll each do one of them. Which drawer would you like to work with?

[image]

[image]

If you pick the messy drawer, you're going to have to pick up a random piece of cutlery, figure out what it is and what you should do with it, pick up the appropriate utensil, and bend/sharpen/paint it. You will be picking up and putting down the appropriate utensil constantly, which is annoying and inefficient.
Either that, or you pick a utensil and have to rifle through the drawer in order to get all the cutlery of the appropriate type, and that's ineffective too because of the time if takes to make sure that you've found all of the (e.g.) forks.

Comparatively, the clean drawer is much easier: pick up the appropriate utensil (e.g. paint brush), work your way through the stack of appropriate cutlery (e.g. forks), and repeat. You don't need to constantly switch utensils or waste time rifling through the drawer.

The analogy is quite fitting: you should have stored your separate types into collections of their own:

```
List<Foo> myFoos = new List<Foo>() { new Foo(), new Foo() };
List<Bar> myBars = new List<Bar>() { new Bar(), new Bar() };
List<Baz> myBazs = new List<Baz>() { new Baz(), new Baz() };

foreach(var myFoo in myFoos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myFoo.FooValue);
}

foreach(var myBar in myBars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myBar.BarValue);
}

foreach(var myBaz in myBazs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myBaz.BazValue);
}
```

This prevents you from needed to up/downcast constantly, and instead you can rely on knowing the correct type at all times. It creates much cleaner code, and the overhead cost of instantiating multiple collections is completely negligible, especially when compared to the constant casting and type checking you have to otherwise do.

---

**Interfaces can help in some cases**

In *some* cases, it can be a valid approach to create a specific interface and let the classes implement the interface in their own way. For example, assuming you want all your classes to give you a message:

```
public interface IMessageGiver
{
    string GiveMessage();
}

public class Foo : IMessageGiver
{
    public string GiveMessage()
    {
        return $"I'm a foo and I have a {this.FooValue}!";
    }
}

public class Bar : IMessageGiver
{
    public string GiveMessage()
    {
        return $"I'm a bar and the time is {DateTime.Now}!";
    }
}

public class Baz : IMessageGiver
{
    public string GiveMessage()
    {
        return $"I'm a baz and I love {this.BazValue}!";
    }
}
```

Now that you've defined a common interface for these classes, you're able to address them by that interface and treat them the same way, which means you *are* able to put them in the same list:

```
List<IMessageGiver> myList = new List<IMessageGiver>()
{
    new Foo(),
    new Bar(),
    new Baz()
};

foreach(var messageGiver in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(messageGiver.GiveMessage());
}
```

Remember how I started off by saying to never pile things together if you intend to treat them differently? Well, we're piling things together here, but it's not a problem because we are treating each object on the pile the same way (we call its `GiveMessage()` method).
Now, it's perfectly fine to pile them together since they are effectively being handled the same way.

---

**To summarize**

There are two solutions to your problem. Either:

- Don't lump different types together if you intend to treat them differently based on their type
- Define a common interface which all the types implement in their own way

Comment: Thank you for this - very helpful. In my case all seven of my classes are components of an assembly (one of the classes). That is why I want to handle them in one list.

Comment: @Eric: I used `object` as a generalized example of a shared base class (since all classes ultimately derive from it), but the same argument applies to _any_ shared ancestor type that your seven types inherit or implement, directly or indirectly.

Comment: What I learned is that not only do Interfaces define a contract between the object and it's user but it can also be used in a sense as a way to define a secondary way to use objects. If you implement an Interface then you can use it to do things with all object that have properties and methods implemented that Interface. This is really powerful and really helps a lot on this project. I have classes that can be in a sense two different things at once. As long as I define and implement them properly I can deal with them properly in their context. They are in a sense a "shadow" class.

Comment: @Eric: I think that's a reasonably accurate summary. Just to add a concrete example which I think helps with understanding the intended use case: There are many car brands, but someone who is able to drive one car is able to drive all cars, because all cars have the same interface (steering wheel, pedals, gear stick, in the same location). Their common interface enables drivers to use cars _interchangeably_, instead of separately needing to learn how to drive each brand of car.